# How can I align divs to father div in the center? Html css

Tags: html, css

I want to align to center the `div class="button"`

Where is my problem?

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
            
.buttons {
   width: 50%;
   height: 70px;
   text-align: center;
   align-content: center;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.button{
      
 }
            
.button a {  
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: Assistant;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 35px; 
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
            
.blue-rectangle {
   background: rgba(83, 121, 125, 1); text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; width: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="blue-rectangle">
            <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button"><a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_A5pnrS">קנה טרולי שחור</a></div>
            <div class="button"><a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_AFCt5O">קנה מזוודה קשיחה</a></div>
            <div class="button"><a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_A3bMkC">קנה טרולי מדוגם</a></div></div></div>
        
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look to flexbox properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the buttons class to display flex, aligned its children to center and justify every content inside the buttons class element to center. You can remove the div.button and use the button class directly with anchor element.

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
            
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
            
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: Assistant;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 35px; 
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
            
.blue-rectangle {
   background: rgba(83, 121, 125, 1);
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-rectangle">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_A5pnrS" class="button">קנה טרולי שחור</a>
    <a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_AFCt5O" class="button">קנה מזוודה קשיחה</a>
    <a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_A3bMkC" class="button">קנה טרולי מדוגם</a>\
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the display property of the buttons class.

```
.buttons {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try opening it into a full-page

```css
body {
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            
            .buttons {
                width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        align-content: center;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0 auto;
            }
      .button{
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
      }
            
            .button a {
       
        font-family: Assistant;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center; 
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 35px; 
        padding: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        text-align: center;
            }
            
            .blue-rectangle {
                background: rgba(83, 121, 125, 1);
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="blue-rectangle">
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="button"><a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_A5pnrS">קנה טרולי שחור</a></div>
                <div class="button"><a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_AFCt5O">קנה מזוודה קשיחה</a></div>
                <div class="button"><a href="https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_A3bMkC">קנה טרולי מדוגם</a></div></div></div>
        
</body>
```

Comment: what changed did you do?

Comment: i added these values in .blue-rectangle:

                height: 100vh;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;

Comment: thank you
but I want them in one line

Comment: Update the answer with the relevant information that you added in the comment.